# SSIS 2012 - Conditional Split and Rejoin in Control Flow Stops

Tags: sql, ssis, constraints

I have created an SSIS package to process some file imports, manipulation, etc but am having a problem with a conditional split I have created.

I have an Execute SQL Task which simply does a count of a table. One constraint has an expression for if the result is 0 and the other if its greater than 0. For the constraint where it is 0, I have three more Execute SQL Tasks for dropping and creating various tables. For the other constraint, it jumps past these three tasks to the next Execute SQL task, lets called it Bob for now. The equal 0 constraint once complete rejoins to Bob and then the remainder of the package.

When I run the package, the zero condition is met, the three Execute SQL Tasks are complete and then it stops, saying package execution complete. It does not appear to be rejoining the main stream.

I have tried putting the three tasks in a Sequence Container but made no difference. I have obviously done something strange or missed a configuration somewhere. If anyone could shed any light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unbelievable. I've sorted it. The last constraint with the equal 0 part needed the logical OR option setting.

Comment: Too bad you can't award your own answer on stack ;)